# Pass Localstorage json data into php sql query through Ajax (A read posts later function)

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm trying to build a "read later"(favorites) function for my blog website.
I want to use localstorage to save the postID of my blog posts (often very short posts) as json and then through simple AJAX (no jquery) POST and php GET, show the save post on one page

I write the postID list to the localstorage the following way save.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.list li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.list li:hover:after,
.list li.fav:after {
  content: ' \2605';
  color: rgb(255, 203, 0);
}
.list li.fav:hover:after {
  content: ' \2606';
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="list">
  <li id="1">PostID1</li>
  <li id="2">PostID2</li>
  <li id="3">PostID3</li>
  <li id="4">PostID4</li>
  <li id="5">PostID5</li>
  <li id="6">PostID6</li>
</ul>
<script>
// get favorites from local storage or empty array
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];
// add class 'fav' to each favorite
favorites.forEach(function(favorite) {
  document.getElementById(favorite).className = 'fav';
});
// register click event listener
document.querySelector('.list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var id = e.target.id,
      item = e.target,
      index = favorites.indexOf(id);
  // return if target doesn't have an id (shouldn't happen)
  if (!id) return;
  // item is not favorite
  if (index == -1) {
    favorites.push(id);
    item.className = 'fav';
  // item is already favorite
  } else {
    favorites.splice(index, 1);
    item.className = '';
  }
  // store array in local storage
  localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
});
// local storage stores strings so we use JSON to stringify for storage and parse to get out of storage
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It returns the following localstorage input (if I add postID 1 and 2):

```
favorites ["1","2"]
```

What I'm struggling with is how to the pass the data (Guess some AJAX, but I have no knowledge on how to do that) to my query that shows the posts.

If I manually paste the values (see variable $q, it works, but I do not know how to do this with simple ajax.

The post list, where I want the data that get's passed to be on is see-saved-posts.php

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); ?>
    <?php
        $q = ("1,2");

            try {

                $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postSlug, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts_seo WHERE postID IN ('.$q.')  ');
                while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                    echo '<div>';
                        echo '<h1><a href="'.$row['postSlug'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
                        echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).' in ';

                            $stmt2 = $db->prepare('SELECT catTitle, catSlug FROM blog_cats, blog_post_cats WHERE blog_cats.catID = blog_post_cats.catID AND blog_post_cats.postID = :postID');
                            $stmt2->execute(array(':postID' => $row['postID']));

                            $catRow = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                            $links = array();
                            foreach ($catRow as $cat)
                            {
                                $links[] = "<a href='c-".$cat['catSlug']."'>".$cat['catTitle']."</a>";
                            }
                            echo implode(", ", $links);

                        echo '</p>';
                        echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
                        echo '<p><a href="'.$row['postSlug'].'">Read More</a></p>';             
                    echo '</div>';

                }

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        ?>
```

Thanks in advance. P.s. I'm new to this community, but have been using it for years. Usually I can find an answer through the search function, but not this time.

Comment: You are right you will need AJAX. Localstorage can only be accessed through js as its client side service. PHP is a server side language. You will need to make an AJAX call to posts page and passing the favourites ids and then retrieve the post and display it. I shall a solution once i get on the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have created a div with id saved-posts. This is where will print the saved posts we get from the AJAX call. I have created a function called `getPosts()`, this performs an AJAX call to the see-saved-posts.php page passing a query string called q with the favourite ids. I called the getPosts function twice, once when the page is loading and again once you update the favourites. One chane you will have to make in the `see-saved-posts.php` page is to make is to get the favourites ID from the querystring by do this: `$q = $_GET['q'];`

**Update**

I have updated the function so that i will only do AJAX call in there are any favourites. If all favourites are removed then it will remove from the remaining one from the page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .list li {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .list li:hover:after,
        .list li.fav:after {
            content: ' \2605';
            color: rgb(255, 203, 0);
        }
        .list li.fav:hover:after {
            content: ' \2606';
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="list">
    <li id="1">PostID1</li>
    <li id="2">PostID2</li>
    <li id="3">PostID3</li>
    <li id="4">PostID4</li>
    <li id="5">PostID5</li>
    <li id="6">PostID6</li>
</ul>


<div id="saved-posts"></div>


<script>
    // get favorites from local storage or empty array
    var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];
    // add class 'fav' to each favorite
    favorites.forEach(function(favorite) {
        document.getElementById(favorite).className = 'fav';
    });

    getPosts(); // calls AJAX to populate with saved posts

    // register click event listener
    document.querySelector('.list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var id = e.target.id,
            item = e.target,
            index = favorites.indexOf(id);
        // return if target doesn't have an id (shouldn't happen)
        if (!id) return;
        // item is not favorite
        if (index == -1) {
            favorites.push(id);
            item.className = 'fav';
            // item is already favorite
        } else {
            favorites.splice(index, 1);
            item.className = '';
        }
        // store array in local storage
        localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));

        getPosts(); // Call AJAX to repopulate with saved post
    });
    // local storage stores strings so we use JSON to stringify for storage and parse to get out of storage

    function getPosts() {
        if (favorites.length) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("saved-posts").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "see-saved-posts.php?q=" + favorites, true);
            xhttp.send();
        } else {
            document.getElementById("saved-posts").innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have worked my way in to the script and done a lot of searches to understand how it functions. Is there anything I should be aware of with the Ajax GET function. I mean, the Localstorage is very easy to change and manipulate. Would there be a possible vulnerability in terms of people trying to inject different values in to it?

Comment: Well as you said injection is one. I am not sure of any others. But to counter this I would suggest checking whether q is what it i supposed to be. Q is supposed to be a number followed by 0 or more comma and number. You would test in php using regex like `/^\d+(,\d+)*$/`